# How to prevent the active region from setting the primary selection?

Tags: region, clipboard

After switching to 24.5.1<sup>1</sup> from some ancient version, Emacs started to spam my primary selection: Whenever I mark a region, or *even move the point using e.g. arrow keys when the mark is active*, a **new entry** appears in my Parcellite history. This makes it unusable.

- I want Emacs changing the primary selection when I mark some text using the mouse.
- I don't care about what happens when using keyboard (pressing `M-w` is easy).
- *But there must be only a single such entry in the history*.

Maybe it's not Emacs' thing at all and it's Parcellite capturing every selection? No idea, but it used to work on Ubuntu 10.04 (now I'm on 16.04).

---

<sup>1</sup> x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9) of 2016-04-17 on lgw01-04, modified by Debian

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick :- `(setq select-active-regions 'only)`

This will make sure that emacs will only save the temporarily active regions to the primary selection, i.e those made with the mouse or shift keys.

Comment: This mayn't be exactly what I want, but it makes Emacs usable again. Thanks a lot.